# How can I create a hook that reacts to an event to load more data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a functionality where if a user clicks on a `LOAD MORE` button, it returns more data.

I already have some code done but every time I click on the `LOAD MORE` button, it removes the first 12 items and sets the new 12 items, but I don't want that, I want to keep the 12 old tems, It is just a regular load more functionality.

```js
const Comp = ({ data }) => {
  const postsPerPage = 12
  const [postsToShow, setPostsToShow] = useState([])
  const [next, setNext] = useState(postsPerPage)

  let arrayForHoldingPosts = []

  const loopWithSlice = (start, end) => {
    const slicedPosts = data.products.slice(start, end)
    arrayForHoldingPosts = [...arrayForHoldingPosts, ...slicedPosts]
    setPostsToShow(arrayForHoldingPosts)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loopWithSlice(0, postsPerPage)
  }, [])

  const handleShowMorePosts = () => {
    loopWithSlice(next, next + postsPerPage)
    setNext(next + postsPerPage)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {postsToShow.map(p => <div>...</div>)}
      <button onClick={handleShowMorePosts}>Load more</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Besides that, I need to turn this into a hook which I am going to using across the whole application.

What am I missing?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need an array `arrayForHoldingPosts`  instead just use
`setPostsToShow( [...postsToShow, ...slicedPosts]);`

`arrayForHoldingPosts` is becoming empty array after every renders so old data is lost.

Hook example

```
const useLoadMore = (data, postsPerPage = 2) => {
  const [postsToShow, setPostsToShow] = useState([]);
  const [next, setNext] = useState(postsPerPage);

  const loopWithSlice = (start, end) => {
    const slicedPosts = data.slice(start, end);
    setPostsToShow( [...postsToShow, ...slicedPosts]);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loopWithSlice(0, postsPerPage);
  }, []);


  const handleShowMorePosts = () => {
    loopWithSlice(next, next + postsPerPage);
    setNext(next + postsPerPage);
  };

  return { handleShowMorePosts, postsToShow }

}


const App = ({data}) => {
  const {handleShowMorePosts, postsToShow } = useLoadMore(data)

  return (
    <div>
      {postsToShow.map((p) => (
        <div>...</div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleShowMorePosts}>Load more</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you know how can I turn this into a hook?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an issue,

`strong textlet arrayForHoldingPosts = []`

this will allocate empty array on each render.

setPostsToShow should be,

```
const loopWithSlice = (start, end) => {
const slicedPosts = data.products.slice(start, end)
setPostsToShow(posts=>([...posts, ...slicedPosts]))
}
```

Comment: Do you know how can I turn this into a hook?

Comment: Can you please be more specific, what exactly you want to do ?

Comment: I need to have a useLoadMore hook where I can use it across the application I am building.

Comment: You can make one generalize component, which renders the **load more button** and accept the data as props and will return new data. it is possible by making generalize component. @Reacting I think you need, this rather than custom hook.